# Real reputation cap showing wrong on my Recent activity page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I encountered a strange reputation cap behaviour on Super User.

I got only 112 today, as reported on my recent activity page, but it has already given me the corresponding badge and stopped counting.

This is not funny, I even didn't got bored for now!

Why can this happen?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your recent activity page (envelope icon), with the "today" and "reputation" tabs selected.

Answer (score 3):

Hit the 'Today' button in the Recent Activity page, then look at the number displayed on the Reputation tab.  That will show you the daily total you've received so far.

Remember that downvotes decrease the daily cap also.

Comment: So did I, and it shows only 112. I even provided a link in post.
About downvotes: there is only one I did. Also can you please send me to a paragraph about in FAQ maybe?

Comment: @whitequark, it won't let me see your 'recent activity' page, you'll have to provide a screenshot for us to see

Comment: Again, I thought that if there is user ID in url it will be accessible to anyone. Why add it otherwise?

Comment: @whitequark, The userID is in there so that the server can direct you to your specific 'recent activity', AND for it to check whether you have permission to see that page.  Otherwise, downvotes wouldn't be anonymous.  We can see your 'profile' page though.

Comment: @hitequark: I suspect you have the "summary" tab selected rather than "reputation", which does not show the full day's tally but only the last 5 highest-ranked posts.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the definition of "today" is ambiguous on the site.  As Lance points out, clicking on the "today" link will give you everything since the rep clock reset, and should show you where the difference is.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that I do not need to click 'today' when it is ALREADY selected. Strange through.

Comment: @whitequark - If you notice none of the buttons are highlighted when you first go to the page. The default view starts at whatever time you first opened the page or some cached value reset not 00:00:00 UTC. To get the full day you have to click on "today".

Comment: @ChrisF: When you switch to the reputation tab (or any other tab), "today" is highlighted (at least for me, currently), but it still doesn't show the whole day. Not very intuitive, but probably status-bydesign.

Comment: @sth - When I click on the envelope I get to the all not highlighted state.

Comment: @ChrisF: But *then* click on one of the tabs...

Answer (score 1):

My [Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=&sf=&su=25472&meta=&mode=today&showflair=true) shows you getting 200 today. I suggest you compare the rep shown there with the values in the page.

Comment: @Jon, I notice that downvotes (1pt from me downvoting) don't show in your tracker.

Comment: @Lance: Indeed - I don't get them in the json. They don't count against the rep cap either, mind you.

Comment: @Jon, I just hit my rep cap on Meta, at 198.  I had no downvotes against me, and two downvotes I'd given.  So I think the downvotes you give do count against the cap.

Comment: @Jon, I checked on your Tracker, and it shows that I have 200.  Hopefully when they get the API done, you'll be able to tweak it.

Comment: @Lance: They don't count against the cap which is *why* you've only gained 198 for the day - 200 from the cap, and -2 from your downvotes. If downvotes given reduced the rep cap, you'd have gained 200 (assuming you've received more upvotes).